# Development in HTML

Tags: wordpress, migration, hosting

My website was develop in HTML and i'm trying to migrate this to a word press, I entered to my host and I created a wordpress site but in the domain of the website that was developed and then the the HTML website disappears and convert into a wordpress site but i can't manage the plugins inside. Like the plugins have a kind of mistake or failure. The host that I used was hostmonster.

Comment: Hi there people! if any one have this problem, here is the solution.
 You should Login into the host that contains your domain and wbsite developed only in HTML, then you go to create new website in wordpress and select the domain, the last website are going to be erased and transform into a wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

At this address, you can see the list of plugins and also install a new plugin:

```
example.com/wp-admin/plugins
```

**Put your site address instead of `example.com`.**